# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' python web-scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping, attributeerror

I'm following this tutorial and I got this error even though I did everything correctly. This's the tutorial link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY&t=241s and this's my code below

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/-/de/dp/B07RF1XD36/ref=lp_16225007011_1_6?s=computers-intl-ship&ie=UTF8&qid=1581249551&sr=1-6'

headers ={"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()

print(title.strip())
```

This's the error message I got when I run the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 26, in <module>
    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: Your "find" call is returning None.

Comment: yeah I know, why though?

Comment: @LifeLearner I'll hazard a guess and say that its because it didn't find the element you were searching for. Are you sure that there is an element with id `productTitle` in the page you are fetching, and that the page was retrieved successfully?

Comment: the instructor gets otherwise when he runs the code but when I run my code I get None!!?

Comment: the page does not have any element with id 'productTitle', try to do it with another page that does contain an element with that id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the title of the product from that page all you need to do is change the parser from `html.parser` to `html5lib` or `lxml`. The latter two have the capability to fix some botched up html elements which in this case do not let you parse the title. I've also implemented random user agent within the script to make it robust.

Working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/-/de/dp/B07RF1XD36/ref=lp_16225007011_1_6?s=computers-intl-ship&ie=UTF8&qid=1581249551&sr=1-6'

page = requests.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent':ua.random})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html5lib')
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
print(title)
```

Comment: Tried with another website writing a similar code like title = soup.find("div",{"class":"jsx-2771165322"}).get_text(strip=True)
print(title) and it works but it doesn't work with Amazon!!?

Comment: I tried again and found it working. The thing is you need to try quite a few times to find success as amazon is very good at detecting bots.

Comment: `headers` plays an important role here. When you use any headers which is identical in each requests, the chance of getting banned by amazon is very high. However, with the above implementation, you can go further. Thanks.

Comment: so this library from fake_useragent import UserAgent will generate fake requests instead of identical requests such as headers=headers?